# Maple plot range

Tags: soft-question, maple

I've been searching for a while, but I can't seem to find the syntax for this (if it exists!) Is it possible to plot a range but exclude certain values? I wish to plot a single graph that ranges from $-\pi<x<\pi$, and excludes the origin. I have a bit of a blow up point and discont=true doesn't work.

Edit: For clarity, that's what I'm trying to plot, but at the origin I get the unwanted lines streaming out.

[image]

Comment: Is there any certain function in your mind?

Comment: @B.S. It's a bit long to type, but involves $1/sin(x)$ if that's a help?

Comment: @B.S. I've added a pic to see.

Comment: @B.S. I would just like to exclude the origin, $\pi$ and $-\pi$

Comment: @B.S. Could you plot from say $s=-\pi + 0.1 . . 0$ and $s=0 . . -0.1+\pi$ and join them together? I can't seem to get both on one plot whilst changing the range.

Comment: I saw what you inserted in the sheet  above the ranges, but I am thinking about an efficient better code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Maple 17.02 on 64bit Linux I get a plot like the following with both the code fragments below. (Well, the curves look less jagged in Maple itself.)

[image]

```
restart:
with(plots):
r:=s->1/2*(C/sin(s)+((C/sin(s))^2+4*a^2)^(1/2)):
zeta:=s->r(s)*exp(I*(s+alpha)):

complexplot( [seq(eval(zeta(s),[C=i,a=2,b=1,alpha=0]),i=-20..20)],
             s=-Pi+0.0001 .. -0.0001+Pi, -10..10, -10..10,
             discont=[usefdiscont=true]);

restart:
with(plots):
r:=s->1/2*(C/sin(s)+((C/sin(s))^2+4*a^2)^(1/2)):
zeta:=s->r(s)*exp(I*(s+alpha)):

complexplot( [seq(eval(zeta(s),[C=i,a=2,b=1,alpha=0]),i=-20..20)],
             s=-Pi-2 .. 2+Pi, -10..10, -10..10,
             discont=[usefdiscont=[bins=11,order=2]]);
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I did try discont=true initially, but the evaluation never ended!